# Excel risk matrix array using drop down lists

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix, dropdown

Im trying to calculate a risk score in my sheet using drop down selections. There is the risk probability & risk impact that would be selected from the dropdowns.
[Dropdown Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWMhO.png)

There is also the risk matrix with corresponding score on a different sheet in the same workbook.

[Matrix Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTAWN.png)

I need a function that allows the user to select the probability from the dropdown, the impact from the dropdown and then send the score to the same sheet from the matrix. Please help.

Comment: Try Index-Match

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Link below to solution if anyone else needs to know

[Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/384535/excel-calculation-based-on-user-input-from-dropdown-fields)